# Converting date to ISO8601 from char array

Tags: c

I've got a date and a time as floats.

```
float thedate = 20161115;
float thetime = 181011.377500;
```

I want to convert them to ISO8601 date-time format, in other words, write them to a file as "2016-11-15T18:10:11.377500"

I managed to get these values inside of a char array by doing the following:

```
char datetimestr[64];
snprintf(datetimestr, sizeof(datetimestr), "%8.0f%f", thedate, thetime);
printf(datetimestr);
```

And this prints: "20161115181011.377500"

I've read that functions such as `strftime` and `strptime` can parse these numbers and output them properly, but for that I guess I need some arch specific headers?

What is the recommended way to achieve what I need? Ideally in a way that runs everywhere.

Any help or further references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, `strftime` is part of the standard C library. Try reading their manual page and documentation. You'll find them anywhere you'll find C library documentation.

Comment: Are these numbers always guaranteed to be in this format, e.g. would 6th August 2016 be 20160806? If so then it's integer maths and printf().

Comment: @tinman yes, they are guaranteed to always be in this format.

Comment: What language are you using? You've tagged two different ones.

Comment: The `printf(datetimestr)` should be changed to either `puts(datetimestr)` or `printf("%s", datetimestr)` (note that there are some differences between these options w.r.t. newlines).

Comment: float for a date format is not a good idea.  Precision issues abound.

Comment: The SO way for posting a self-answer is to post it as an answer and not as an edit to your question.  Recommend reverting this post and adding your own answer.  As it stands, your "answer" has a number of flaws.

Comment: @chux, thx. Would you tell me what flaws, so that I can learn and correct them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code could print the values and then parse them again

```
int main() {
  long thedate = 20161115;
  float thetime = 181011.377500f;
  char buf[80];
  snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%+08ld%+08f", thedate, thetime);
  int y,M,d,h,m;
  float s;
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, "%5d%2d%2d%3d%2d%f%n", &y, &M, &d, &h, &m, &s, &n);
  if (n) {
    // ISO 8601 specifies a sign must exist for distant years.
    printf((y >= 0 && y <= 9999) ? "%4d" : "%+4d" , y);
    printf("-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02.6f\n", M, d, h, m, s);
  }
  puts(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
2016-11-15T18:10:11.375000
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use some math on the input values to extract their individual components, for example:

```
int theyear = thedate / 10000;
int themonth = (thedate - (theyear * 10000)) / 100;
...and so on
```

Then you can build up your string using `sprintf()`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll give it a try right away

Answer (score 1):

Out of luck. Not enough precision.

Typical `float` cannot represent `20161115.0` and will save as `20161116.0f` instead.

Consider other types.  Suggest `long thedate`.

Type the following to see what is really saved in `thedate`

```
volatile float f = 20161115.0f;
printf("%.10e\n", f);
```

Suspect output will be `2.0161116000e+07`

Comment: I hadn't even noticed that. Thanks for your comment. I changed that to `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments and answers. I've followed suggestions and it seems to work out quite fine (with the exception of milliseconds, but that should be easy to fix)

Here's the code:

```
long thedate = 20161115;
float thetime = 181011.377500;

int y = thedate / 10000;
int m = (thedate - (y * 10000)) / 100;
int d = (thedate - (y * 10000) - (m * 100));

int h = thetime / 10000;
int min = (thetime - (h * 10000)) / 100;
int sec = (thetime - (h * 10000) - (min * 100)) / 1;
float mili = thetime - ((float)h * 10000) - ((float)min * 100) - (float)sec;

printf("%i-%i-%iT%i:%i:%i%.6f\n",y,m,d,h,min,sec,mili);
// Outputs : 2016-11-15T18:10:110.3775000
```

Comment: Printing with `"%i`" does not print with the number of digits that ISO 8601 specifies.  Use `"%2i`.  Also use `0` to properly print values less than 10  like `"%02i`.  Certainly the print  is wrong with `110.3775000` seconds. as the leading 0 of milliseconds appearers.  Various truncation to `int` issues with `/100` and `float`.